# How do I change the format of date stored as string values when written to flat file?

Tags: sql, date, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package which contains the following flow. The package has two Data Flow Tasks.

#### Data Flow Task 1:

In the first data flow task, output from a stored procedure involving multiple tables in different databases is written to two tables in a database.

#### Data Flow Task 2:

In the second data flow task, output from one of the above mentioned tables is written to a Flat File.

All the tables involved in the package have a column name **`BirthDate`** of data type **`VARCHAR(10)`**. This column contains date values as string in the format YYYYMMDD.

Data written to the flat file is being saved in the format *`YYYY-MM-DD`*. However, I want the date value to be written to the flat file in the format *`MM-DD-YYYY`*

#### Questions:

1. How can I achieve the date format *`MM-DD-YYYY`* within the flat file?
2. Do I need to change the column data type from VARCHAR(10) to some other data type in the tables? I have lots of tables in various databases.

Comment: Date and Time Styles under [`CAST`and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)?

Comment: Change in all tables in Database?

Comment: All the tables should be `datetime` if they hold a date & time. Is that your question?

Comment: How Do i write that function?

Answer (score 1):

I use a data conversion tool for similar situation, no need to change the source table data types. It help maintain source and destination table integrity.

[image]

Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks for reply. If i'm doing other way, e.g inserting from table to Flat file, do i have to change column data types in Flat file connection manager? I was reading through it. What is derived column? Do i have to perform that one in DFT?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework has some very nice string manipulation capabilities, and a Script Transformation would take care of this problem easily. Add a Script Transformation Component to your dataflow; in the Input Columns section of the Script Transformation Editor, make sure you include `BirthDate` in the Available Input Columns grid and set its UsageType to `ReadWrite`. Then, this little bit of C# code will convert your YYYYMMDD strings to MM-DD-YYYY:

```cs
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    DateTime birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
        Row.BirthDate, 
        "yyyyMMdd",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Row.BirthDate = birthDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
}
```

With respect to your second question: Ideally, if you're storing a date in a database, you **should** be using the appropriate datatype. You might want to ask around your organization to find out why all those BirthDate columns were defined as `VARCHAR` - there may well have been a good reason at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always `YYYYMMDD` -- that is, zero-filled like *20130221*, I'd just use simple string functions:

```
SUBSTRING([Birthdate],5,2) + '-' 
+ SUBSTRING([Birthdate],7,2) + '-' 
+ SUBSTRING([Birthdate],1,4)
```

I agree that it would be better to use an actual `datetime` or `date` datatype. But if you can't or won't, then a simple expression like this seems like the easiest way to me.

Comment: I can't imagine that this would be very efficient. Further, OP needs a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. Optimally, you should alter the column to the correct data type:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, wrongtypecol, 120), 110) AS date 
FROM   tbl
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a6f6/1)